# How can I display the contents of an environment variable from the command prompt in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, environment-variables

In Windows 7, when I start the Command prompt, is there any command to display the contents of an environment variable (such as the `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH` variables)?

I have tried with `echo $PATH`, `echo PATH` and `$PATH` but none of these work.

Comment: @Daniel: I know how to set environment variables in Windows, I simply open "System properties" > "Advanced" and "Environment Variables". So I don't expect the answer to my question in a question titled with **"How do I set PATH and other environment variables?"**, because I know that! I'm **not** asking about how to set them.

Comment: Perhaps relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884071/windows-echo-command-cant-echo-a-user-set-variable

Comment: `echo %path:;=&echo.%` gets the pretty list of semicolon separated paths. Works if a variable does not contain special characters like `&` or `^`.

Comment: the command to print path in Windows command shell is:
`path`

Answer (score 840, accepted):

In Windows Command-Prompt the syntax is `echo %PATH%`

To get a list of all environment variables enter [the command `set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) without any parameters.

To send those variables to a text file enter the command `set > filename.txt`

---

Related

- [How to list global environment variables separately from user-specific environment variables?](https://superuser.com/q/1179433/52492)

Comment: Why is this value different from what I've specified in computer properties?

Comment: @Johnny_D It is likely that either you have a user scoped variable or you have a session scoped variable (using the `set` command inside a command prompt does not keep the change after you close the console window) that is overriding it.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, How do you differentiate those set throughout the system vs those that are only for the current user?

Comment: @Pacerier, that would be [a separate question](http://superuser.com/q/1179433/52492)

Comment: Works on Windows 8, 10 and 11 too.

Answer (score 285):

To complement the previous answer, if you're using Powershell `echo %PATH%` would not work. You need to use the following command instead: `echo $Env:PATH`

Comment: Also in PS: `ls env:` for listing all environment variables

Comment: Since PowerShell is now the default shell in modern Windows OS's this needs to be up-voted higher. Way too many answers out there that simply no longer work on modern Windows.

Comment: @Lev. What version do you have that does not have cmd?

Comment: so how one shows a variable if its name contains a dot? Like `artifactory.user.name`? `echo $Env:artifactory.user.name` doesn't work (highlighting suggests that it tries to show the `artifactory` variable)

Comment: i just wish to know WHY.. why it is still windows but yet every shell is not compatible with others. Is there a reason? i really want to know

Comment: @YakovL `${env:artifactory.user.name}`

Answer (score 40):

As an additional bit of information: While *SET* works with global or system variables, sometimes you want to write and read User variables, and this is done with the *SETX* command. SETX is included in the base installs of Windows beginning with Vista, but was also available in Windows XP by installing the Resource Pack.

One difference about SETX though is that you cannot read the variable out in the same command window you wrote it in. You have to write the SETX command in one Command or Powershell window, and then open a new window to read it using ECHO.

SETX can also write global or system variables.

**To Set a *user* variable using SETX:**

```
setx variable value
```

**To set a global or system variable using SETX:**

```
setx /m variable value
```

**To read a user or global variable:**

*Remember, you must open a new Command or Powershell window to read this variable.*

```
echo %variable%
```

Answer (score 16):

From SET /?:

> ```
> SET P
> ```
>
> would display all variables that begin with the letter 'P'

So for example if you want to find value of environment variable %PATH%, you can just type `set path`.

This is 3 characters shorter than `echo %PATH%`, but note that it also lists other variables starting with "path" (e.g. PATHEXT).

Answer (score 10):

Powershell:

```
echo $Env:PATH
```

Command Prompt:

```
echo $Env:%PATH%
```

on the Command Prompt `%PATH%` will also work

Comment: There is no `$Env` on `cmd.exe`. Just use the `path` command or `echo %PATH%`.

Answer (score 9):

To display contents of an environment variable eg. path, at command prompt type: `echo %path%`
To display the values in separate lines, type: `set`
To display all variables starting with "h", type: `set h`
(Press enter after typing to get computer response, duh!)

Above commands are for cmd, not powershell.
In powershell, type: `echo $env:path` or `ls env:path`
To display on separate lines, type: `ls env:`
To display all variables starting with "h", type: `ls env:h*`
To display contents/values of all variables containing "java", type: `ls env:*java*`

Answer (score 6):

The solution was a bit different for me: it won't recognize the system environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, so I had to set `JAVA_HOME` as User environment variable, so that i can use %JAVA_HOME% in system environment variable setting up.

Resuming, I had to:

- add a user environment variable: `%JAVA_HOME%` as:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25";
  ```
- add to `%PATH%` system environment variable:

  ```
  "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;"
  ```
- latter on command line:

  `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, and it retrieved the correct path (before it wasn't recognizing);

  `echo %PATH%`, and it retrieved the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin" composed with %JAVA_HOME% user variable;

And it worked for me. I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 6):

On powershell if you want to list all the values splitter by semicolon delimiter, then use:

```
$env:Path-split';'
```