# Trying to install and create new git repository for first time - I think disconnected work network drive is creating issue

Tags: windows, installation, git

I have windows 7 installed.
`C:\` is a local drive.  `H:\` is a work network drive that continually re-installs every time I boot.  I have learned to just disconnect it whenever I am doing any coding from home or installing coding related apps, as I tend to have issues.

I installed Git and tried to create a repository for the first time.
It gives me the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or
directory error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such
file or directory
     while executing "exec {C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-config.exe} --global --add
 gui.recentrepo C:/Users/bmyhre/Desktop/Testing/projects/skeleton"
     ("eval" body line 1)
     invoked from within "eval exec $opt $cmdp $args"
     (procedure "git" line 23)
     invoked from within "git config --global --add gui.recentrepo $path"
     (procedure "_append_recentrepos" line 16)
     invoked from within "_append_recentrepos [pwd]"
     (procedure "_git_init" line 17)
     invoked from within "_git_init $this"
     (procedure "choose_repository::_do_new2" line 5)
     invoked from within "choose_repository::_do_new2 ::choose_repository::__o1::__d"
     invoked from within ".buttons.next invoke "
     invoked from within ".buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } "
     invoked from within ".buttons.next instate pressed { .buttons.next state !pressed; .buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke
 } } "
     (command bound to event)
```

My guess is that it is trying to reach the `H:` drive somewhere (I installed it with `H:` disconnected), but I don't know where/how to change this so it actually looks where the real `.gitconfig` on the `C:` drive is.
How to avoid this error message?

Comment: Do you have a file like `C:\Users\{username}\.gitconfig` that might be of any interest?

Comment: There is a .gitconfig file at C:\Program Files\Git\etc

Comment: My end solution was to get a Mac. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if you have an %HOME% environment variable defined.

If that variable exists and refers to `H:\` (instead of `%USERPROFILE%`), then it will look for the *global* git config file in `H:\.gitconfig` (meaning `%HOME%\.gitconfig`).

Changing that `%HOME%` variable to a local path like `%USERPROFILE%` would solve that issue.

Comment: Where would I see that?  Here are the contents of my .gitconfig file that exists at C:\Program Files\Git\etc  [core]
 symlinks = false
 autocrlf = true
[color]
 diff = auto
 status = auto
 branch = auto
 interactive = true
[pack]
 packSizeLimit = 2g
[help]
 format = html
[http]
 sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
[sendemail]
 smtpserver = /bin/msmtp.exe

[diff "astextplain"]
 textconv = astextplain
[rebase]
 autosquash = true

Comment: @user1525974 Check first your environment variables ([with `set`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5327495/6309), or [`echo %HOME%`](http://superuser.com/a/341193/141) )

Comment: This worked.  I just created a new environment variable named `HOME` and set the value to `%USERPROFILE%`, worked great.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Note that with the latest Git for Windows (2.4.x: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), this is done for you when running `git-cmd.exe`.

Comment: I did that, and also I have a .gitignore file in %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig but am still getting this error 
`error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Lrrr `.git/config` isn't the same as `~/.gitconfig`: the former is the local config to a repo, the latter is the global config. Are you using git for windows 2.4.4?

Comment: @VonC yes after I post my comment I understand the difference, also your solution solved my global problem :) no I'm using windows 7 service pack 1 and my git version is : `git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2`

Comment: @Lrrr Don't hesite to use the latest one: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: @VonC ok, I'll download that and see if this fix my problem, thanks for your time

Comment: @VonC version 2.4.4 was the answer :) thanks again :)

Comment: @Lrrr Great! See here to see what the differences are between the old msysgit and the new "git for Windows": http://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309