# Set and print content of environment variable in cmd.exe subshell?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Consider this example, where I start a new "sub" instance of `cmd.exe`, and then try to set a new environment variable in it, and then check if it has the proper value set (this is in `cmd.exe` of Windows 10):

```
>cmd /c "SET OPERATION=NEW & SET O"
OneDrive=C:\Users\user\OneDrive
OPERATION=NEW
OS=Windows_NT
```

So, as noted in https://superuser.com/a/776506/688965 - by doing `SET O` I would "*display all variables that begin with the letter 'O'*", and indeed, it shows that an environment variable `OPERATION` exists, and its value is `NEW`. So far, so good.

However, if I try to print the environment value instead, it does **not** expand:

```
>cmd /c "SET OPERATION=NEW & echo %OPERATION%"
%OPERATION%
```

... however, if I try to expand any *other* environment variable, it works ?!:

```
>cmd /c "SET OPERATION=NEW & echo %OS%"
Windows_NT
```

Why does this happen? How can I set an environment variable, and then print it with `echo` in a single line, in a `cmd.exe` subshell?

Comment: "Why does this happen?" The %OPERATION% is executed before it has been set. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why does this happen?

The `%OPERATION%` is expanded (Phase 1) before the variable has been set (Phase 7).

See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) for the gory details:

> Processing a line of code in a batch file involves multiple phases.
>
> Here is a brief overview of the various phases:
>
> Phase 0) Read Line:
>
> Phase 1) Percent Expansion:
>
> Phase 1.5) Remove : Remove all Carriage Return (0x0D) characters
>
> Phase 2) Process special characters, tokenize, and build a cached
>   command block: This is a complex process that is affected by things
>   such as quotes, special characters, token delimiters, and caret
>   escapes.
>
> Phase 3) Echo the parsed command(s) Only if the command block did not
>   begin with @, and ECHO was ON at the start of the preceding step.
>
> Phase 4) FOR %X variable expansion: Only if a FOR command is active
>   and the commands after DO are being processed.
>
> Phase 5) Delayed Expansion: Only if delayed expansion is enabled
>
> Phase 5.3) Pipe processing: Only if commands are on either side of a
>   pipe
>
> Phase 5.5) Execute Redirection:
>
> Phase 6) CALL processing/Caret doubling: Only if the command token is
>   CALL
>
> Phase 7) Execute: The command is executed

Answer (score 7):

#### How can I set an environment variable, and then print it with echo in a single line, in a cmd.exe subshell?

To enable neccessary [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) in a cmd subshell you'll have to use the `/V:ON` switch of [cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) and use an `!` exclamation mark instead of the `%` percent sign.

```
> cmd /V:ON /C "SET OPERATION=NEW&echo [!OPERATION!]"
[NEW]
```

**Just a reminder**
The trailing space in your original set will be part of the variable content:

```
> cmd /V:ON /C "SET OPERATION=NEW &echo [!OPERATION!]"
[NEW ]
```